# How I get obj from parent model in Django Admin to put in html template

Tags: django, django-admin

Here is my code where I generate a PDF file, (like an invoice), but I can't retrieve the fields from the admin.TabularInline.

In my model.py I have to class: Sale and SaleItems,and in admin.py I have :

```
class SaleItemsInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SaleItems
    extra = 1
    readonly_fields = ('total', )
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'100%'})},
    }



@admin.register(Sale)
class SaleAdmin(DjangoObjectActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (
        ('order', 'created', 'due_date'),
        ('profile'),
        ('pay_method', 'tax_card'),
        ('therapist' ,'activity',), 
        ('notes'), 
        ('totals'), 
        ('pay', 'payOne','payTwo'),
        ('subtotal', 'status'),
        )
    readonly_fields = ('created', 'totals', 'order','subtotal', 'status', 'tax_card')
    search_fields = ['profile__name', 'profile__cpf',
                     'profile__phone', 'activity', ]
    autocomplete_fields = ('profile',)
    list_display = ('profile', 'order', 'created', 'due_date', 'totals', 'status')
    inlines = [SaleItemsInLine]
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'30'})},
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':100})},
    }

def generate_pdf(self, request, obj):
    
    html_string = render_to_string('sales/invoice.html', {'obj': obj})

    html = HTML(string=html_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri())
    html.write_pdf(target='/tmp/{}.pdf'.format(obj), presentational_hints=True);

    fs = FileSystemStorage('/tmp')
    with fs.open('{}.pdf'.format(obj)) as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="{}.pdf"'.format(obj)
        return response

    return response
```

I get fields from Sale with {{ obj.name }}, {{ obj.created}}, etc...
How I get the fields  from SaleItems(TabulaInline) ???

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution making a query inside the generate_pdf and passing as a new context:

```
def generate_pdf(self, request, obj):
    qs = SaleItems.objects.filter(sale_id=obj.pk)
    html_string = render_to_string('sales/invoice.html', {'obj': obj, 'qs': qs })
```

...